# SugarCRM SOAP set_relationship between Contacts and Prospect lists bug

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am trying to create a relationship between a Prospect List (target list) and a Contact.

I create a new contact and get the id of a prospect list all using classes I created which are just wrappers for the soap api calls sugar provides.
But the code boils down to this soap call:

```
$this->_sugarsoap->client->__soapCall('set_relationship', array($this->getSessionid(),$relationship));
```

$this->getSessionid() Is the session Id and $relationship is an array which holds this:

```
array
  0 => string 'ProspectLists' (length=13)
  1 => string '180ab1f5-cf7e-d386-50f8-4c18a790e016' (length=36)
  2 => string 'Contacts' (length=8)
  3 => string '76323942-8cbb-3224-f18a-4c19efa80a1b' (length=36)
```

After I try this I always get this error: (I do a var_dump of the returned values of the soap call)

```
object(stdClass)[5]
  public 'number' => string '20' (length=2)
  public 'name' => string 'Module Does Not Exist' (length=21)
  public 'description' => string 'This module is not available on this server' (length=43)
```

This seems like a sugarcrm bug because I do have the contacts module and also the prospect lists module. I know this for a fact because I add a contact via the soap call and also retrieve the id of a prospect list via the soap call.

I found [this thread](http://www.sugarcrm.com/forums/showthread.php?t=41421) in the sugar forums and I did try the code given there but I still got the same error.

Anyone have a solution for this? I really need to associate a contact to a prospect list (target list) via a soap call.

I am using SugarCRM 5.5.0 (I also tried with sugarcrm 5.5.2 and got the same error) on ubuntu server using mysql.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Ok I got this working with the fix from the thread and a little correction on my part. In the array I pass to the set_relantionships function I really have to use the format:

```
 'module1' => 'modnameA',
 'module1_id' => 'modidA',
 'module2' => 'modnameB',
 'module2_id' => 'modidB
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: Hi, can you help me, the set_relationship (without the s) according to the documentation on the API is to receive strings, instead of a hash name-key pair....what is the right format to pass into set_relationship()?

Comment: okay I tried this -- doesn't match the api's but moving along -- but I get a Module does not exist error!?

Comment: Hey Angela! Here I was using the old soap api! The new soap files for sugar are in services/v2 (or something like that). The new soap class a more complicated method but it's a lot better than the old one :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will help you sure:

```
$relationship = array(
  'session' => $session_id, //session id that comes after login by soap
  'set_relationship_value'=>array(
    'module1' => 'Prospect',  // your module name
    'module1_id' => "$ProspectID", // your first module id
    'module2' => 'Contact', // your second module
    'module2_id' => "$ContactId", // send module id
  )
);
```

Use this array. hope this will be helpful to you.